# Leaked connection in weblogic server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, connection-pooling

[image]

Hi All need to know what this leaked connection count stands for?
I have closed all statement and connection object in finally block in my code.
**Is this are connections that are idle longer than max idle timeout or this is count of connections recovered by  Weblogic server which are leaked**.

Answer (score 3):

From WebLogic help page on the administration console:

> Leaked Connection Count
>
> The number of leaked connections. A leaked connection is a connection that was reserved from the data source but was not returned to the data source by calling close().

There are some things that might be causing these leaks. One worth mentioning that might help you (happened to me in the past) is: check the status of the threads on your server (`Environment/Servers/[Your Server]/Monitoring/Threads`). Sometimes, a stuck thread (waiting for I/O or whatever) might cause a connection to reach WebLogic timeout before your code hits close() and so mark the connection as leaked. Anyway, if this is the case, it is generally a code issue. The time between you open a connection and close it should be minimal. The code you run between these calls should also be as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, your connection acquisition/use code is in a try-catch block. The most commonly used solution for this problem is to add a "finally" clause and close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Leaked Connection means WebLogic is unable to recover a unused connection after the idle time out is exceeded. Usually this happens when the front end users session is not closed properly.

Further read available [*here*](http://blog.sysco.no/db/locking/jdbc-leak/)